# Calendar functionality help using jquery ,ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been trying hard to get the data from the clicked checkboxes using jquery but not able to get data of one variable.

I want to save like for example if i click on 2-3 time and day is monday and when i click on save time sheet it should save these values into database but i am not getting value of time in variable ,but i am getting value of day when i alert it on submit.

Check this link for getting clear idea.
[calendar](http://www.developingsense.com/calendar)

[code](http://www.developingsense.com/code.txt)

Comment: can you post the specific code you are having problems with here, (and maybe illustrate the problem using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)), that way the solution to your problem can help other people with the same problem who visit this site.

Comment: why don't you use [data variables] instead (http://www.broken-links.com/2010/11/18/data-attributes-in-html-and-jquery/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is this line

```
$('input').click(function()
```

It sets your `text` var when you click on a checkbox, but when you click on your submit button, which is also an `input`, it overwrites the `text` value.

Use the `:not()` selector, so that it does not bind your click function when the input is the select button

```
$('input:not(#submit)').click(function()
```

see this jsFiddle example, using `:not(#submit)` - http://jsfiddle.net/wBNGP/

Comment: Thanks Sean , it worked. Also , how can i get multiple checkbox values in a variable as it is showing only the last checked value on alert? I am beginner in jquery ,any help will be appreciated.